# SQL, ORACLE: Update the value of a column with different values

Tags: sql, oracle

I searched a lot and could not find answer to my question yet.
So, I have to generate a lots of data (millions of rows) into different tables, and **this script should be fast**.
Now let's speak about 3 specific tables, in these there are id rows:

- in table **Owners** the id starts from 10000, incremented by 1 (with sequence)
- in table **Cars** the id starts from 10000000, incremented by 1 (with sequence).

Into the third table, called **Ownership**, I have to "merge" these IDs with some specific rates:

- 50% of the owners have 1 car
- 20% of the rest owners have 2 cars
- 10-10-10% of the rest will have 3, 4 and 5 cars

**Important things:**

- note for **Owners** and **Cars** tables: rates: for 100 unit owners, 210 unit cars will be generated, and in the **Ownership** table the cars will be unique, so 210 rows will be in this table too
- first the **Owners**, then the **Cars** rows will be generated
- then I insert into the **Ownership** table some values "from" **Cars**

Notes: Here is how I generated rows into **Cars** (**Owners** is similar)
(It will generate v_custom_unit pieces rows, this unit is calculated from the rates which I give a few lines ago (for 100 unit owners, 210 unit cars will be generated and 210 unit Ownerships too), and then I used a for loop to multiply the rows):

```
insert /*+ APPEND */ into Cars(
    carId
  , carType
  , ...
)
select /*+ PARALLEL */
    seq_carid.nextval as carId
  , REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'Suziki,Toyota,Subaru,Saab,Hyundai,Opel,Volkswagen', '([^,]+)', 1, ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,7)) ) as carType
  , ...
from dual
connect by level <= v_custom_unit;
```

Multiplying is like this:

```
FOR i in 1..v_forSteps LOOP

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
      insert /*+ APPEND */ into Cars (
          carId,
        , carType,
        , ...
      )
      SELECT /*+ PARALLEL */
          seq_carid.nextval as carId,
        , carType
        , ...
      FROM Cars
      WHERE ROWNUM <= ' || v_custom_unit;

      COMMIT;

END LOOP;
```

The next step is to generate Ownership rows:

```
insert /*+ APPEND */ into Ownership (
     ownerId
   , carId
   , date_bought
)
select /*+ PARALLEL */
     1
   , c.carId
   , some_random_date as date_bought
from Cars c;
```

Here comes my problem: Every car is in the Ownership with ownerId=1.
**My question is: how can I update the *Ownership* table with different owner values in a single update (and maybe to maintain the rates (50%-20%-10%-10%-10%))?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways to do it:

```
insert into ownership (ownerid, carid, bought)
  with t(oid, cid, cnt) as ( 
    select 1, 1, 1 from dual
    union all 
    select case when oid <= 5 
                     or oid <=  7 and cnt >= 2 
                     or oid <=  8 and cnt >= 3 
                     or oid <=  9 and cnt >= 4 
                     or oid <= 10 and cnt >= 5 then oid + 1
                else oid 
           end, 
           cid + 1, 
           case when oid <=  5 
                     or oid <=  7 and cnt >= 2 
                     or oid <=  8 and cnt >= 3 
                     or oid <=  9 and cnt >= 4 
                     or oid <= 10 and cnt >= 5 then 1
                else cnt + 1 
           end
    from t where cid < 21) 
  select oid, cid, trunc(sysdate) - round(dbms_random.value * 1000) from t
```

This is a demo for 10 owners and 21 cars. Not sure about efficiency, but this is only one recursive query. Oracle 11g required.

Test table and output:

```
create table ownership (carid number(6), ownerid number(6), bought date);

  CARID OWNERID BOUGHT
------- ------- -----------
      1       1 2013-12-29 -- one car
      2       2 2015-12-16
      3       3 2014-04-04
      4       4 2013-12-17
      5       5 2013-11-20
      6       6 2014-04-04 -- two cars
      7       6 2015-09-05
      8       7 2013-12-19
      9       7 2016-01-02
     10       8 2015-08-22 -- three 
     11       8 2014-03-05
     12       8 2016-07-14
     13       9 2015-09-02 -- four 
     14       9 2015-08-28
     15       9 2015-06-04
     16       9 2014-04-20
     17      10 2016-08-07 -- five 
     18      10 2015-07-16
     19      10 2014-12-08
     20      10 2016-04-26
     21      10 2014-05-30
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Unfortunately I got a new information after I have posted the question which made the data generation easier, but I will accept this as the answer, because it's useful, and I would had to operate with the numbers in the query to generate more rows.
Soon I will share my solution, if you are (and anyone else is) interested in it.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to fill empty tables with test data and performance is important you may consider leaving dml and sequences aside. To maintain rates you may use function `ownerId = f(carId)` on the base of remainders.

```
--drop table owners;
--drop table cars;
--drop table ownership;

create table owners as
  select level n
    from dual
    connect by level < 1000*1000*1;

create table cars as
  select level n
    from dual
    connect by level < 2100*1000*1;

create table ownership as
  select level cid,
         10*trunc(level/21) + case
                                when mod(level, 21) between 0  and  4 then mod(level, 21)
                                when mod(level, 21) between 5  and  6 then 5
                                when mod(level, 21) between 7  and  8 then 6
                                when mod(level, 21) between 9  and 11 then 7
                                when mod(level, 21) between 12 and 15 then 8
                                when mod(level, 21) between 16 and 20 then 9
                              end oid
    from dual
    connect by level < 2100*1000*1;
```

And check result:

```
with
  cars_by_owner as (
    select oid, count(*) cnt
      from ownership 
      group by oid),
  owners_by_cars_count as (
    select cnt, count(*) c, grouping(cnt) rg
      from cars_by_owner
      group by rollup(cnt))
select f.cnt "cars count",
       f.c "owners count",
       round(f.c/s.c*100) "%"
  from owners_by_cars_count f
  join owners_by_cars_count s
    on f.rg = 0 and s.rg = 1

cars_count  owners_count  %
    1       499999        50
    2       200000        20
    3       100000        10
    4       100000        10
    5       100000        10
```

It takes me several seconds to create 1M owners 2.1M cars and fill `ownership` table.

If you will encounter ORA-30009, you may generate a helper table with positive numbers instead of using `connect by level`.